# Calculating optimal number of clusters with Nbclust()

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I would like to calculate the optimal number of clusters for a large dataset: 17 columns and >80.000 rows.

This is my code:

## 1. Definition of the path

```r
setwd("C:/Users/A/Documents/Master BWL/Masterarbeit")
```

## 2. Loading the required packages

```r
library(factoextra); library(cluster); library(skmeans); library(mclust); 
library(fpc); library(psda); library(simEd); library (ggpubr);
library(dbscan); library(clustertend); library(MASS); library(devtools);
library(ggbiplot);library(NbClust)
```

## 3. Import csv file

```r
WKA_ohneJB <- read.csv("WKA_ohneJB_PCA.csv", header=TRUE, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

WKA_ohneJB_scaled <- scale(WKA_ohneJB)

# NbClust ()
nb <- NbClust(WKA_ohneJB_scaled , distance = "manhattan", min.nc = 2, max.nc = 7, method = "kmeans")
```

```r
dput(rbind(head(WKA_ohneJB, 10), tail(WKA_ohneJB, 10)))
structure(list(X = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
821039L, 821040L, 821041L, 821042L, 821043L, 821044L, 821045L, 
821046L, 821047L, 821048L), BASKETS_NZ = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    LOGONS = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), PIS = c(71L, 39L, 50L, 4L, 
    13L, 4L, 30L, 65L, 13L, 31L, 111L, 33L, 3L, 46L, 11L, 8L, 
    17L, 68L, 65L, 15L), PIS_AP = c(14L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 8L, 0L, 1L), 
    PIS_DV = c(3L, 19L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 38L, 
    8L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 2L), PIS_PL = c(0L, 5L, 8L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 24L, 0L, 6L, 32L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), PIS_SDV = c(18L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 0L), PIS_SHOPS = c(3L, 
    24L, 13L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 28L, 2L, 11L, 71L, 16L, 2L, 5L, 
    6L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 2L), PIS_SR = c(19L, 0L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 23L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 32L, 1L, 
    0L), QUANTITY = c(13L, 2L, 18L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
    1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 17L, 8L), WKA = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), NEW_CUST = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), EXIST_CUST = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), WEB_CUST = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), MOBILE_CUST = c(0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), TABLET_CUST = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
    LOGON_CUST_STEP2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 821039L, 821040L, 821041L, 
821042L, 821043L, 821044L, 821045L, 821046L, 821047L, 821048L
), class = "data.frame")
```

> Error: Error in na.omit(jeu1) : object 'polygons' not found

Comment: Providing a part of your data set with ```dput(rbind(head(WKA_ohneJB, 10), tail(WKA_ohneJB, 10)))``` might help others to reproduce the problem you have there.

Comment: @knytt I provided part of my dataset. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: The scaling using ```scale``` function creates ```NaN```s in some of the columns, are you sure you want to use all the columns for clustering?

Comment: @knytt Yes I want to use all columns. As this is a large data set, do I have to reduce the dimensionality before running NbClust?

Comment: In general I would recommend dimensionality reduction, but that is very general question...
Regarding your question, I was not able to reproduce your error message, the ```NbClust``` always returns different errors. One of the problems is in the scaling, where you scale a column that contains only ones or zeroes, thus returning ```NaN``` also your first column probably contains some kind of identifier, thus you should not use it for clustering.

Comment: @ knytt Thank you for your help. The use of the elbow criterion and the silhouette plot are certainly well suited to determine the number of my clusters. Concerning my data set I would have two more basic questions. Which methods of dimension reduction and cluster algorithms could you recommend for large datasets? Is it better to exclude the columns with the dummy variables or not to scale the data before cluster analysis?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209795/discussion-between-as123-and-knytt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple means of determining number of clusters is to examine the *elbow* in the plot of within groups sum of squares and/or average width of the silhouette, the code produces simple plots to examine these...

In order to perform clustering, you need to solve the problem of `NaN`s after scaling...

```r
WKA_ohneJB_scaled <- as.matrix(scale(data[, c(-1, -2, -18)]))

plot_scree_clusters <- function(x) {
  wss <- 0
  max_i <- 10 # max clusters
  for (i in 1:max_i) {
    km.model <- kmeans(x, centers = i, nstart = 20)
    wss[i] <- km.model$tot.withinss
  }
  plot(1:max_i, wss, type = "b",
       xlab = "Number of Clusters",
       ylab = "Within groups sum of squares")
}

plot_scree_clusters(WKA_ohneJB_scaled)

plot_sil_width <- function(x) {
  sw <- 0
  max_i <- 10 # max clusters
  for (i in 2:max_i) {
    km.model <- cluster::pam(x = pc_comp$x, k = i)
    sw[i] <- km.model$silinfo$avg.width
  }
  sw <- sw[-1]
  plot(2:max_i, sw, type = "b",
       xlab = "Number of Clusters",
       ylab = "Average silhouette width")
}

plot_sil_width(WKA_ohneJB_scaled)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the Elbow Method, as alluded to by knytt.  Here are a couple references that describe the technique.

https://www.r-bloggers.com/finding-optimal-number-of-clusters/

https://uc-r.github.io/kmeans_clustering#elbow

Also, consider using the Affinity Propogation library.  The AP library will automatically determine the optimal number of clusters for you.  Check out the siple example below.

```
install.packages("apcluster")

library("apcluster")
c1 <- cbind(rnorm(30,.3,.5),rnorm(30.7,.4))
c2 <- cbind(rnorm(30,.7,.4),rnorm(30.4,.5))
x1 <- rbind(c1,c2)

plot(x1, xlab="", ylab="", pch=19, cex=.8)

apresia <- apcluster(negDistMat(r=2),x1)

s1 <- negDistMat(x1,r=2)
apres1b <- apcluster(s1)

apresia

plot(apresia, x1)
```

[image]

Resource:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/apcluster/vignettes/apcluster.pdf